# ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

```
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:tranquil-crag-9767.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:tranquil-crag-9767.git'
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  I have checked that everything is properly set up, and the connection to git is good.

Comment: vlad schnakovszki i have already looked through that and there are different circumstances causing my error

Comment: Make sure in addition to your " git add . " you also do " git add -u " to remove old files.  That fixed it for me.

Comment: I was trying a standard git push without "heroku master". Seemed to work before but pushing explicitly to heroku master seemed to fix it for me. I also git RM'd some deleted files but that didn't seem to help me.

Comment: I had similar problem with django and heroku, I divided my settings file in base, local and production, so my mistake was to not set heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

Answer (score 11):

First try to pull your master from heroku.

```
$ git pull heroku master
```

and then push it again. If you are still getting the same error then push your code with force

```
$ git push heroku master -f
```

Comment: i am able to pull, but when i try to pull using force i get the same error, any ideas?  It says failure to compile ruby app

Comment: no m not saying pull it with force, i said push it with force

Comment: if it still produce same error, then may b u have syntax error in your  html/js/css

Comment: i have made several apps and had the same problem, is it possible it is an issue with my computer?

Comment: failed to push some refs to--> means your master is not updated, thats why i had given above solution, other reason if your precompiling failed, it means you have some syntax error in html/css/js

Comment: the correct syntax is git push heroku master -f not '--f'

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland '--f' will also work.

Comment: @Rahul not true all the time. use -f or --force

Comment: I'm getting this error and it's failing with force.