# error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler

Tags: python, git, heroku, ubuntu-14.04, web-deployment

I have [upgraded pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26964891/2734863) after the error and it didn't change, I have no issues [installing scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821297/scipy-build-install-mac-osx) locally, I have [gcc 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34676103/2734863), I have the [latest version of gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34038311/2734863) (4.8.4), I tried this [fancy gfortran installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29527939/2734863) which seems to be specific to Ubuntu and it did install something, I tried [git pull heroku master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21520601/2734863) but get `fatal: Coundn't find remote ref master,` adding the [--rebase option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9794458/2734863) returns the same error. This makes sense I think since I used the following to delete all apps on Heroku so there shouldn't be anything to pull: `for app in $(heroku apps); do heroku apps:destroy --app $app --confirm $app; done`

The links all link to solutions that purportedly work for what appears to my problem as well or highly similar

I'd like to note that *my app has been deployed successfully before* many months ago. Changes I made include: I modified the code a bit - compiles and runs locally, I want to now add a ~500MB .tiff as well to the site so used `git add` and committed it as if it were any other file. I read somewhere that users have 200MB what I believe is called slug space and GB upon GB of space in a tmp folder so I didn't think space would be an issue. I also reinitialized git as I needed to work from a different directory, but since I deleted all the apps from Heroku I figured no merges would need to be performed (trying to have a fresh start)

**Command:**

```
git push heroku master -f
```

**Result with the first error message I saw close to the top:**

```
remote:          customize IntelFCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable ifort
remote:          Could not locate executable ifc
remote:          customize LaheyFCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable lf95
remote:          customize PGroupFCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable pgfortran
remote:          customize AbsoftFCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable f90
remote:          Could not locate executable f77
remote:          customize NAGFCompiler
remote:          customize VastFCompiler
remote:          customize CompaqFCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable fort
remote:          customize IntelItaniumFCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable efort
remote:          Could not locate executable efc
remote:          customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
remote:          customize GnuFCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable g77
remote:          customize G95FCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable g95
remote:          customize PathScaleFCompiler
remote:          Could not locate executable pathf95
remote:          don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
remote:          building 'dfftpack' library
remote:          error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
remote:          
remote:          ----------------------------------------
remote:          Running setup.py clean for scipy
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for matplotlib: started
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for matplotlib: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Stored in directory: /app/.cache/pip/wheels/94/22/76/2f17479b2ff90623041a1ce6b6c2b88bcd68e4a24dd2456d9f
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for parmap: started
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for parmap: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Stored in directory: /app/.cache/pip/wheels/74/fd/cf/7d03cee9ca1d249a13c3b68e2743dd2127b4c123f632a4a846
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for DataSpyre: started
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for DataSpyre: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Stored in directory: /app/.cache/pip/wheels/b0/ad/2c/f854c06dd738eec9ba91b4798c871cf078cc699bf7b153988c
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: started
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Stored in directory: /app/.cache/pip/wheels/21/92/81/0259bc54d3f52003b6b94825569abf890237f20c2122a2af4f
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cherrypy: started
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cherrypy: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Stored in directory: /app/.cache/pip/wheels/b3/2e/4a/4d94757218472574adad901b155f3fcbd5290a86da272543c9
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: started
remote:          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Stored in directory: /app/.cache/pip/wheels/94/a7/79/f79a998b64c1281cb99fa9bbd33cfc9b8b5775f438218d17a7
remote:        Successfully built matplotlib parmap DataSpyre pandas cherrypy MarkupSafe
remote:        Failed to build scipy
remote:        Installing collected packages: scipy, six, python-dateutil, pytz, cycler, pyparsing, matplotlib, parmap, pandas, cherrypy, MarkupSafe, jinja2, DataSpyre
remote:          Running setup.py install for scipy: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for scipy: finished with status 'error'
remote:            Complete output from command /app/.heroku/miniconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-IpiQEw/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-09yK_9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
remote:            lapack_opt_info:
remote:            openblas_lapack_info:
remote:              libraries openblas not found in ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
remote:              NOT AVAILABLE
remote:            
remote:            lapack_mkl_info:
remote:            mkl_info:
remote:            /app/.heroku/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:635: UserWarning: Specified path  is invalid.
remote:              warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
remote:              FOUND:
remote:                libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
remote:                library_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/lib']
remote:                define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
remote:                include_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/include']
remote:            
remote:              FOUND:
remote:                libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
remote:                library_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/lib']
remote:                define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
remote:                include_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/include']
remote:            
remote:              FOUND:
remote:                libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
remote:                library_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/lib']
remote:                define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
remote:                include_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/include']
remote:            
remote:            Running from scipy source directory.
remote:            Splitting linalg.interpolative Fortran source files
remote:            /app/.heroku/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:635: UserWarning: Specified path /usr/local/include/python2.7 is invalid.
remote:              warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
remote:            blas_opt_info:
remote:            blas_mkl_info:
remote:              FOUND:
remote:                libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
remote:                library_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/lib']
remote:                define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
remote:                include_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/include']
remote:            
remote:              FOUND:
remote:                libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
remote:                library_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/lib']
remote:                define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
remote:                include_dirs = ['/app/.heroku/miniconda/include']
remote:            
remote:            running install
remote:            running build
remote:            running config_cc
remote:            unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
remote:            running config_fc
remote:            unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
remote:            running build_src
remote:            build_src
remote:            building py_modules sources
remote:            building library "dfftpack" sources
remote:            building library "fftpack" sources
remote:            building library "mach" sources
remote:            building library "quadpack" sources
remote:            building library "odepack" sources
remote:            building library "dop" sources
remote:            building library "fitpack" sources
remote:            building library "fwrappers" sources
remote:            building library "odrpack" sources
remote:            building library "minpack" sources
remote:            building library "rootfind" sources
remote:            building library "superlu_src" sources
remote:            building library "arpack_scipy" sources
remote:            building library "sc_c_misc" sources
remote:            building library "sc_cephes" sources
remote:            building library "sc_mach" sources
remote:            building library "sc_amos" sources
remote:            building library "sc_cdf" sources
remote:            building library "sc_specfun" sources
remote:            building library "statlib" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.cluster._vq" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.cluster._hierarchy" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.fftpack._fftpack" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.fftpack.convolve" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.integrate._quadpack" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.integrate._odepack" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.integrate.vode" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.integrate.lsoda" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.integrate._dop" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.integrate._test_multivariate" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.integrate._test_odeint_banded" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/integrate/_test_odeint_banded-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
remote:            building extension "scipy.interpolate.interpnd" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.interpolate._ppoly" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.interpolate._fitpack" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.interpolate.dfitpack" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/interpolate/src/dfitpack-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
remote:            building extension "scipy.interpolate._interpolate" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.io.matlab.streams" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.io.matlab.mio_utils" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg._fblas" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/linalg/_fblas-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg._flapack" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/linalg/_flapack-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg._flinalg" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg._interpolative" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg._calc_lwork" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg._solve_toeplitz" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg.cython_blas" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg.cython_lapack" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.linalg._decomp_update" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.odr.__odrpack" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize._minpack" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize._zeros" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize._lbfgsb" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize.moduleTNC" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize._cobyla" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize.minpack2" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize._slsqp" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize._nnls" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize._group_columns" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.optimize._lsq.givens_elimination" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.signal.sigtools" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.signal._spectral" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.signal._max_len_seq_inner" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.signal.spline" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve._iterative" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve._superlu" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack._arpack" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/_arpack-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._shortest_path" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._traversal" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._min_spanning_tree" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._reordering" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._tools" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse._csparsetools" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.sparse._sparsetools" sources
remote:            [generate_sparsetools] 'scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr_impl.h' already up-to-date
remote:            [generate_sparsetools] 'scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr_impl.h' already up-to-date
remote:            [generate_sparsetools] 'scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csc_impl.h' already up-to-date
remote:            [generate_sparsetools] 'scipy/sparse/sparsetools/other_impl.h' already up-to-date
remote:            [generate_sparsetools] 'scipy/sparse/sparsetools/sparsetools_impl.h' already up-to-date
remote:            building extension "scipy.spatial.qhull" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.spatial.ckdtree" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.spatial._distance_wrap" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.special.specfun" sources
remote:            f2py options: ['--no-wrap-functions']
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.special._ufuncs" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.special._ellip_harm_2" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.stats.statlib" sources
remote:            f2py options: ['--no-wrap-functions']
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:            building extension "scipy.stats.vonmises_cython" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.stats._rank" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.stats.mvn" sources
remote:            f2py options: []
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
remote:              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/stats/mvn-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
remote:            building extension "scipy.ndimage._nd_image" sources
remote:            building extension "scipy.ndimage._ni_label" sources
remote:            building data_files sources
remote:            build_src: building npy-pkg config files
remote:            running build_py
remote:            copying scipy/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy
remote:            copying build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/__config__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy
remote:            running build_clib
remote:            customize UnixCCompiler
remote:            customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib
remote:            customize Gnu95FCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable gfortran
remote:            Could not locate executable f95
remote:            customize IntelFCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable ifort
remote:            Could not locate executable ifc
remote:            customize LaheyFCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable lf95
remote:            customize PGroupFCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable pgfortran
remote:            customize AbsoftFCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable f90
remote:            Could not locate executable f77
remote:            customize NAGFCompiler
remote:            customize VastFCompiler
remote:            customize CompaqFCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable fort
remote:            customize IntelItaniumFCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable efort
remote:            Could not locate executable efc
remote:            customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
remote:            customize GnuFCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable g77
remote:            customize G95FCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable g95
remote:            customize PathScaleFCompiler
remote:            Could not locate executable pathf95
remote:            don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
remote:            building 'dfftpack' library
remote:            error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote: Command "/app/.heroku/miniconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-IpiQEw/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-09yK_9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-IpiQEw/scipy
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python/Conda app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to brain-image-analyzer.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/brain-image-analyzer.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/brain-image-analyzer.git'
```

I am sadly not using a well-known framework like Django or Flask and instead using [Spyre](https://github.com/adamhajari/spyre) and am following deployment instructions from [here](http://adamhajari.github.io/2015/04/21/deploying-a-spyre-app-on-heroku.html) which *have worked for me before*

Do I need to make a symbolic link...? Maybe it is looking in the wrong place and I need to force it to the Fortran compiler by unceremoniously teleporting it there? This is the only thing I can think of I haven't tried. I just don't know where to point the link though.